# distance+load assignment matlab OR cplex

Tags: matlab, variable-assignment, cplex

I am trying to solve an optimization problem on MATLAB or CPLEX. We have two sets A (n elements), and B (m elements). We have to assign exactly one element in A to one element in B.

A single element in B can be assigned as many elements in A as needed (maximum n). There is a cost of assigning an element i in A to an j element in B = **cij**.

Moreover, there is another cost associated with the NUMBER of elements in A assigned to a element in B (load). That cost is:  **lj = ( sum (number of elements assigned to j) ^2 )**

The overall cost is therefore: **sum (cij+lj)**

We would like to find the optimal assignment such that: sum (cij+lj) is minimized.
The problem can be formulated as a binary integer programming IF there was no load. My concern is how can I write such a function in either MATLAB or CPLEX.

Answer (score 0):

You wish to minimize the cost of this assignment from one vector to another, subject to the number of variables to be assigned, from 1 to `n` inclusive?  If so:

```
[x,fval] = fminsearch(@(x) sum(arrayfun( @(y) y*cij+y^2,1:n)),1)
```

or

```
function out = minFunc(x,n)
  out = 0
  for ii=1:n
    out = out + cij*ii + n^2;
  end
end
```

Where cij=1 for demonstration purposes and Ij = N^2, N = number of elements assigned to j.  This seems to simplistic for your needs since it will always return `x = 1`.  However, the variable to be minimized `x`, is not used, so I'm not sure what you are trying to minimize.  Please let me know if I may help further.